# Why are jpgs changed to png after resizing?

Tags: bricelambson-image-resizer

Love image resizer, so easy.

Just got a new pc with Win10 (which sucks!)

When I run resizer on jpg, the new file is in png format. 
Tried looking in options to force a jpg output
I don't see any way to deal with this..suggestions?

Comment: Who's "image resizer"?

Comment: http://www.bricelam.net/ImageResizer/

Comment: I'm assuming by this [readme file](https://github.com/bricelam/ImageResizer/blob/master/README.md) that the developer watches SuperUser waiting to help anyone with questions?

Comment: that's my assumption....

Comment: well, what does it say when you click 'advanced options… '?